# Raphael.js get rectangle coords after transform

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a small little game I'm making in javascript and Raphael.js(which i'm fairly new to) and I'm making a turret essentially, just a circle that has a rectangle swivel around it. And that works fine and dandy!
Code for transform is :

```
this.self = this.self.animate({ transform : this.transform }, 250);
```

However, I need to find the coords of the rectangle after I animate it, but getBBox() keeps getting the same coords. Does anyone have any suggestions? A visual picture of the transform would be:
[image]

So I need the turret coords after the transformation. I need to find the front of the turret so I know where the bullet needs to come out of! Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

By using the rotation number, will help you to find the coordinates. Lets say the rotation angel is q = 45 degrees.

This means that `y` changes by a*sin(q) and `x` changes by a - a*cos(q).

**EDIT**

Pay attention to all cases. In this particular case, both coordinates got decreased, but if you turn to southeast, then `y` increases and `x` decreases. Or if northwest: `y` and `x` decrease.

Comment: so the formula is y= a*sin(a) and x=a-a(cos(a)) ?

Comment: Note that the angle is in radians. So for 45 degrees it should be `sin(Math.PI/4)`. But generally it's better to just keep measuring the angles in radians if you don't need to display it to a human. Just get used to `2*PI === 360 degrees`.

Comment: Will it still work if say, I know its 30 degrees so I just do sin(30) ?

Answer (score 0):

Transform is just a visual effect, it's not affects on coordinates.
You know width of turret and you know rotation angle.
Use sin & cos to calculate new coords.

X = Math.cos((i * Math.PI) / 180) * R + x;
Y = Math.sin((i * Math.PI) / 180) * R + y;

i - angle
R - width of turret
x and y - turret offset

Comment: I know for the triangle I have all the side's lengths. 2 sides are the circle radius, and the other is the rectangle width. But I'm not very good at math, I'm not sure how to get the new coordinates still. :(